# What is Function/Class Module to read all the headers from collection?

Tags: excel, vba, function, collections

I have a set of collections to read into a collection.

Defining all of the columns is troublesome & the columns will grow in the future.

Below is the sample code in which I need to define all the columns in a class module first, then I can use the columns in a module.

Class modules:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public COL_ID As Integer
Public PCT_GRTHAN As Double
Public PCT_LESSTHAN_EQUAL As Double
Public TIME_BUCKET As String
Public NO_OF_GROUPS As Integer
Public sum As Integer
Public PCT As Double
```

My code:

```vb
Sub UtilProfReport()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim row As Long

    Dim col3 As New Collection

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim i As Long, UtilProf As clsUtil
    For i = 2 To rg.rows.Count
    
        If rg.Cells(i, 1).value > 0 Or i = 1 Then
            Set UtilProf = New clsUtil
            
            UtilProf.COL_ID = rg.Cells(i, 1).value
            UtilProf.PCT_GRTHAN = rg.Cells(i, 2).value
            UtilProf.PCT_LESSTHAN_EQUAL = rg.Cells(i, 3).value
            UtilProf.TIME_BUCKET = rg.Cells(i, 4).value
            UtilProf.NO_OF_GROUPS = rg.Cells(i, 5).value
            UtilProf.sum = rg.Cells(i, 6).value
            UtilProf.PCT = rg.Cells(i, 7).value
                
            col3.Add UtilProf
        End If
    Next i
    
    Worksheets.Add

    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    sh.Range("A1").value = "UTIL"
    sh.Range("A2").value = ">"
    sh.Range("B2").value = ChrW(&H2264)
    sh.Range("C2").value = "# Groups"
    sh.Range("D2").value = "%"

    ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False
    sh.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableAnimations = False
    End With
    
    With sh.Range("A1:D1")
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
        .Interior.Color = 15849925
    End With
    
    sh.Range("A2:D2").Interior.Color = 14277081
    
    Dim UtilProfout As clsUtil
    For i = 1 To col3.Count
        row = i + 2

        With sh
            Set UtilProfout = col3(i)
            .Cells(row, 1).value = UtilProfout.PCT_GRTHAN
            .Cells(row, 2).value = UtilProfout.PCT_LESSTHAN_EQUAL
            .Cells(row, 3).value = UtilProfout.NO_OF_GROUPS
            .Cells(row, 4).value = UtilProfout.PCT
        End With
     Next i
     
End Sub
```

Below is idea output
[image: Output]

How to write user defined function/class module to load the raw data in excel worksheet so that I do not need to dim every header for the sheet?
I expect the class module/ function to not only be used for this raw data, expecting the class module/function can be used to load other worksheets in same workbook.

Foe example, for the class module I can use the readfile function.
[image: readdile]

Comment: Maybe have a look at [ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to loop through the class module variables in VBA. You can use an array instead of a class module:

```
For i = 1 To rg.Rows.Count
    ' Add current row as array
    coll.Add rg.Rows(i).Value

Next i
```

You can retrieve it like this:

```
Dim arr As Variant
' Get array at position 1
arr = coll(1)
```

You can write it to the worksheet like this:

```
Dim j As Long, arr As Variant
For i = 1 To coll3.Count
    arr = coll3(i)
    
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        .Cells(Row, j).Value = arr(1, j)
    Next j
Next i
```